# Apache Flume with 2 different interceptors on same source

Tags: apache, selector, interceptor, flume

I am trying to add 2 different interceptors on the same source and send the intercepted data to 2 different channels.
But, I was not able to configure the same. Couldn't find any documentation about the same. Also, I am having some issues with the channel selectors. Not sure how to select a channel with the different interceptors.

Here is my code so far:

```
a1.sources = syslog_udp
a1.channels = chan1 chan2
a1.sinks = sink1 sink2 //both are different kafka sinks


a1.sources.syslog_udp.type = syslogudp
a1.sources.syslog_udp.port = 514
a1.sources.syslog_udp.host = 0.0.0.0
a1.sources.syslog_udp.keepFields = true

a1.sources.syslog_udp.interceptors = i1 i2
a1.sources.syslog_udp.interceptors.i1.type = regex_filter
a1.sources.syslog_udp.interceptors.i1.regex = '<regex_string1>'
a1.sources.syslog_udp.interceptors.i1.excludeEvents = false

a1.sources.syslog_udp.interceptors.i2.type = regex_filter
a1.sources.syslog_udp.interceptors.i2.regex = '<regex_string1>'|'<regex_string2>'
a1.sources.syslog_udp.interceptors.i2.excludeEvents = false

a1.sources.syslog_udp.selector.type = multiplexing
a1.sources.syslog_udp.channels = chan1 chan2


a1.channels.chan1.type = memory
a1.channels.chan1.capacity = 200
a1.channels.chan2.type = memory
a1.channels.chan2.capacity = 200
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is no straight-forward setup for this.
A work-around for this kind of layout is to have a single/wider channel interceptor in one agent, pipe the output to an avro-sink and setup a new agent for the avro-source and set-up the new channel interceptor on that.